# Create a model record when a button is pressed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a project, and I'm trying to implement a feedback system. There are three buttons, positive, neutral and negative and at the moment when the user clicks a button they are asked if they want to submit more feedback and are taken to the new feedback form. However instead what I want is that when a button is pressed a record is saved with the rating field of the model set by which button they pressed.

Then when a user gives more feedback they are taken to the edit page for that feedback. I'm not really sure how to go about doing this, would I need some javascript on the buttons? or does rails have a method that will do this?

Thank you

Comment: What you you tried so far?

Comment: I'm not really sure where to start, like I said at the moment the model record is created and saved by going to the new form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a form for each button with a hidden field. Set the hidden field value to positive, neutral or negative. You try using an enum here instead.

```
<% form_for :feedback, url: feedback_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :sentiment, value: 'positive' %></td>
    <%= submit_tag "Positive" %>
<% end %>

<% form_for :feedback, url: feedback_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :sentiment, value: 'neutral' %></td>
    <%= submit_tag "Neutral" %>
<% end %>

<% form_for :feedback, url: feedback_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :sentiment, value: 'negative' %></td>
    <%= submit_tag "Negative" %>
<% end %>
```

You could put the above in a simple loop to DRY it up.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, though when I try this I get an error saying:

No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"feedbacks"} missing required keys: [:id]

I assume this means it's trying to call the update method rather than the create method?

Comment: Above is just an example of how you do this. For details look at the Rails documentation. This should help: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object